# Any lisp code highligher for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, lisp, syntax-highlighting

I have a personal Wordpress page and plan to post lisp codes. By default Wordpress does not support code highlighter for lisp. Any recommendations?

Comment: check https://gist.github.com/

Comment: @ferruccio: if, cond, defun, defvar, defparameter, defclass, return, special variables, keyword arguments...and more! :P

Comment: If you look through https://gist.github.com/valvallow, then @zhanxw can see what Github's LISP syntax highlighting looks like, and @ferruccio can see what there is to highlight.

Comment: It's a hack, but you might try `M-x htmlfontify-buffer` and export this thing.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) with a [custom version of `lang-lisp.js`](https://matthias.benkard.de/code/contributions/prettify/lang-lisp.js).  It's been working great so far.

For an example usage, see [a random Lisp-related article](https://matthias.benkard.de/journal/57) pulled from my archives.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using a combination of [Syntaxhighlighter Evolved](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/) for general highlighting and a slightly modified version of [Brian Carper's brush](http://briancarper.net/blog/556/) for Clojure. Brian also has a nice color scheme that matches pretty closely the coloring I use in emacs.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use [gist](http://gist.github.com) which has an option to be embedded in any html page.